# How to get wifi or 3G internet speed programmatically in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, wifi, avplayer

I need a custom video player which play based on internet speed and I have four video urls which is hd,high,medium and low quality here what I am doing is I am playing high resolution video when internet speed with certain limit and something like fast and want to play based on wifi or 3G speed and here the problem is I am not able to get internet speed. I searched lot of sites for this. and one more point is while playing I have to check internet spped for every 10 secs.

Comment: There is not API proving the speed, you can however detect the connection type (EDGE, 3G, 4G, WiFi, etc). You will need reachability and [`CTTelephonyNetworkInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using AVFoundation for video playback, an easier solution to your problem is rather than creating four video files, convert the video for use with HTTP Live Streaming, which allows the player select the most appropriate bitrate media stream.

https://developer.apple.com/streaming/